# Assign value of object and nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, assign

So, basically, I have this object (in vue data()):

```js
...
detail: {
  title: 'I have no idea',
  date: 2020-02-12,
  sender: {
    name: 'John Cenna',
    username: 'john10'
  },
  receipent: {
    name: 'Katleen',
    username: 'katmeow'
  },
  ....
}
```

Now, I want to assign all of them to be null (for validation process, kind of) but couldn't assign the nested object (the object without child is fine with just loop). How do I do this? thank you

Comment: You will probably need to use some form of loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution:

1. Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate the key-value entries of the object as follows. Note that `Object.entries()` returns an empty array for non-objects.
2. If the entry's value is already `null` or `undefined`, return.
3. If the entry's value is an array, recurse on each array item (go to step 1 with the array item as the new object to evaluate).
4. If the entry's value is an object, recurse on the object.
5. Otherwise, set the entry's value to `null`.

```js
const data = {
  detail: {
    title: 'I have no idea',
    date: 2020 - 02 - 12,
    sender: {
      name: 'John Cenna',
      username: 'john10'
    },
    receipent: {
      name: 'Katleen',
      username: 'katmeow'
    },
    items: [
      { id: 100, name: 'Apple' },
      { id: 200, name: 'Banana' },
      { id: 300, name: 'Orange' },
    ]
  }
}

function nullify(obj) {
  // 1
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    // 2
    if (v === null || v === undefined) {
      return
    }
    // 3
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      return v.forEach(nullify)
    }

    // 4
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      nullify(obj[k])
    } else {
      // 5
      obj[k] = null
    }
  })
}

nullify(data.detail)
console.log('res', data.detail)
```

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem, imagine I have to add {  id: 400, name: 'Peach' } to the "items" within this object. I've tried thousand ways, none of them works, this is an array, but push wont work, since it is inside an object. Thank you.